# ithit ajaxbrowser not open webdav folder, but response data is correct

Tags: webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

request(google-chrome console):

```
Request URL:https://<name>:5553/myproxy.cgi?5443/

Request Method:PROPFIND
Status Code:207 Multi-Status
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic dmJveDp2Ym94
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:241
Content-Type:text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Cookie:settingsCookie=5-9-5-0; Auth=Basic%20dmJveDp2Ym94; testCookie=test
Depth:0
Host:<name>:5553
Origin:https://<name>:5553
Referer:https://<name>:5553/Browser/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.70 Safari/537.17
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
5443/:
Request Payload
<?xml version="1.0"?><propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop><resourcetype/><displayname/><creationdate/><getlastmodified/><getcontentlength/><getcontenttype/><supportedlock/><lockdiscovery/><quota-available-bytes/><quota-used-bytes/></prop></propfind>
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive
Content-disposition:attachment; filename=
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:449
Content-Type:text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Date:Wed, 20 Feb 2013 05:37:37 GMT
Expires:Wed, 20 Feb 2013 05:37:37 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=59
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.1c DAV/2
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

responce data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:ns0="DAV:">
<D:response xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp2="http://apache.org/dav/props/" xmlns:g0="DAV:">
<D:href>/</D:href>
<D:propstat>
<D:prop>
<lp1:resourcetype><D:collection/></lp1:resourcetype>
<lp1:creationdate>2013-02-18T12:59:45Z</lp1:creationdate>
<lp1:getlastmodified>Mon, 18 Feb 2013 12:59:45 GMT</lp1:getlastmodified>
<D:supportedlock>
<D:lockentry>
<D:lockscope><D:exclusive/></D:lockscope>
<D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
</D:lockentry>
<D:lockentry>
<D:lockscope><D:shared/></D:lockscope>
<D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype>
</D:lockentry>
</D:supportedlock>
<D:lockdiscovery/>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
</D:propstat>
<D:propstat>
<D:prop>
<g0:displayname/>
<g0:quota-available-bytes/>
<g0:quota-used-bytes/>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
</D:propstat>
</D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

status and data are correct but it throw error NotFoundLocation. 
I suppose that problem maybe in comparing send/receive "folder" non identical.
please, post your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in href element. Yours is

```
<D:href>/</D:href>
```

Here is what I'm getting with another server:

```
PROPFIND http://ajaxbrowser.com/User3b0f54c/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ajaxbrowser.com
Depth: 0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Content-Length: 957
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0

<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>http://ajaxbrowser.com/User3b0f54c/</d:href>
    <d:propstat><d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status><d:prop><d:resourcetype><d:collection /></d:resourcetype><d:displayname>User3b0f54c</d:displayname><d:creationdate>2013-03-12T23:16:11Z</d:creationdate><d:getlastmodified>Tue, 12 Mar 2013 23:17:59 GMT</d:getlastmodified><d:supportedlock><d:lockentry><d:lockscope><d:exclusive /></d:lockscope><d:locktype><d:write /></d:locktype></d:lockentry><d:lockentry><d:lockscope><d:shared /></d:lockscope><d:locktype><d:write /></d:locktype></d:lockentry></d:supportedlock><d:lockdiscovery /></d:prop></d:propstat><d:propstat><d:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</d:status><d:prop><d:getcontentlength /><d:getcontenttype /><d:quota-available-bytes /><d:quota-used-bytes /></d:prop><d:responsedescription>Property was not found</d:responsedescription></d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

Do you use mod_dav?
Can you post full response with headers?